# Why button_to method does not set to delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Although documentation of `button_to` is straight forward, I get method `post` instead of `delete`

Here is my implementation:

```
= button_to experiment_path(experiment), params: {tr_number: tr_counter}, remote: true, form: { "data-type" => "script"}, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, :style=>"padding: 3px;", :class=>'btn btn-danger', :method => :delete do
    %i{class: 'fa fa-trash'}
```

the result is:

```
<form data-type="script" class="button_to" method="post" action="/en/experiments/10170-dc-voltage-inverter-using-capacitor" data-remote="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
  <button data-confirm="Are you sure?" style="padding: 3px;" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx">
  <input type="hidden" name="tr_number" value="0">
</form>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Look at `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">` - it is delete. Does it work as expected?

Comment: No, it will send a post request

Comment: Let's try simpler version: `button_to "Sth", some_path, method: :delete, params: { tr_number: tr_counter }` and check if it generates delete action.